# How to customize top nav of model driven app of Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365, model-driven-app

How can I customize the top nav of model driven app.

[image]

I need to customize the top nav and add a link or button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the command bar (previously known as the ribbon bar).

There is a decent bit of documentation at [Customize commands and the ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/customize-commands-ribbon).

You effectively need to download the Dynamics solution and edit the XML of the solution.

> Both the command bar and the ribbon use the same underlying XML data
> to define what commands to display, when the commands are enabled, and
> what the commands do.

However, there are community tools that make this process significantly easier - [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx).